# How to automatically find, load and install wireless drivers in Linux?

Tags: debian, shell, wifi, drivers

When I install Debian Linux for my and my friend's laptops by using a net-install image(downloaded [here](https://www.debian.org/distrib/)), after I start the installation, it can usually automatically select a correct wireless network adapter's driver and then continue. How is it implemented?

Here is what I have tried: first, try to mount the installer image to see what's in it:

```bash
sudo mount ~/download/debian-12.5.0-amd64-netinst.iso /mnt/mobile/
```

Read the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to find what's the initrd.

Then try to see what command is in the initrd:

```bash
lsinitramfs /mnt/mobile/install.amd/initrd.gz
```

You can see some executable files like hw-detect; however, I can't understand how it works, or whether it is the correct command to detect and install hardware drivers.

And you can see some wireless drivers in `/firmware` :

```bash
ls /mnt/mobile/firmware
amd64-microcode_3.20230808.1.1~deb12u1_amd64.deb
atmel-firmware_1.3-7_all.deb
bluez-firmware_1.2-9_all.deb
......
```

I don't know how to automaticlly install that.

Apoligize: it's the first time I have ever ask in StackExchange, so if I did something wrong, I'll feel sorry and correct soon. And English is not my mother language so please forgive me for my errors in language.